# How to find voltages of a node using commands in lt spice?

Tags: ltspice

[image]

I am simulating this circuit, how do i find the voltage of the diode through the error log in each step of the the voltage source through a command? I tried using the .meas command but it just shows nothing.

Comment: Couldn't tell you, but here's a better way https://tinyurl.com/ydr4ro3z

Comment: Have you tried adding names to the nodes (with `F4`)?

Comment: yes even if i added the name to the node i still dont know what command to execute to find the voltages of the diode per step of voltage source

Comment: @AedenSchmidt Why didn't you ask in clear "how should I use `.MEAS` to find out the voltage across two nodes?". Your title implies you can't find the names, and the question says you used `.MEAS` but couldn't find the nodes. Don't edit anything now, you've got an answer. Make sure to select it if it resolves your problems. Also, use the ping `@<TAB>` to notify the users when replying, otherwise they will never know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used .meas TRAN  Vdiode FIND (V(Va) - V(vn)) AT = 5m

where Va and Vn are the node names on either side of the diode.

[image]